# Application of calculus

Tags: calculus

[image]

Let $f:R \to R$ be a function such that $f'''(x)$ is positive for all $x \in R$ and let $x_1 < x_2.$  Show that $f(x_2)-f(x_1) > f'\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)(x_2-x_1).$

Comment: I edited you typing; make sure it's what you want.  On this site, it's considered rude to post problems without explaining where you're stuck and why.

Comment: @B.Goddard It's not considered at all rude: it's just a sign that the OP is new and has misunderstood the purpose of this site.  Try to be a bit nicer to new users in future.  And yes, this site is not a place where you can ask any question and immediately get an answer: you need to explain why you're interested in the problem, what you've tried already and why it's not working.

Comment: Can it be done by considering the slope of tangents and applying ivp

Comment: Hint: Use the Lagrange-Taylor formula:
$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f^{\prime}(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(c)$$
(with $c$ strictly between $a$ and $x$) for well chosen values of $a$ and $x$.

Comment: @JohnGowers  I was nice.  I edited his post and I informed him politely of his faux pas.  How about if you be less sanctimonious in the future?